# Event Listener or onClick - Best Practice

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have an HTML page with around 100 text boxes. I currently use a JS event listener (blur) to detect when a user leaves a text box. Within the event listener I use `if` statements to filter the action depending on which text box was used, i.e. `if id == blah`, `if className == blahblah`, etc.

Would it be considered a better practice to place `onBlur()` in the HTML tag of each text box in order to direct the action to specific functions, or am I on the right track?

Comment: The best practice is to have javascript between the script tags and no inline javascript in HTML. In your specific case maybe there is a better way then to have 100 if statements. Can you post a sample of your code as it is now so we maybe help with ideas?

Comment: I would use an array for the elements, and another for the eventlisteners... then you would be able to simply iterate over them and identify them with their index

Comment: A couple of questions: Does every textbox need the same function? If so does every textbox with some className have the same function? Do you need to support IE8 and up? (addEventListener is one of your tags but isn't supported in IE8)

Comment: Please post some HTML, you might get very useful help!

Comment: I started off using inline calls in my HTML. Then I switched to event listeners. Based on your replies I think I'll put all the calls through event listeners. Most text boxes use the same functions. I also have a lot of labels that change their graphics when clicked. These are all currently inline. I'll change them also.

Comment: Lastly a question on jQuery. My webpage is actually a large form for collecting data on a tablet. It uses Application Cache to still function when there is no internet connection. If I used jQuery would the whole library need to be downloaded and referenced in the manifest?

Comment: I missed commenting on IE8 support. The form is used within a single company so it doesn't need to operate with different browsers or versions. I'm currently using Chrome and IE10 for development.

Answer (score 1):

Hey buddy as rightly told by Sergio. Its better to have event handlers in script element by DOM approach.
Now to simplify your task use EVENT DELEGATION
just attach `document.body.onchange=detect`

```
function detect()
{
var textboxvalue=event.target.value //event.target point to text box on which blur event fires
}
```

This simple code will do your task by bubbling of event. No need to use any arrays/conditionals/classes/ids/seperate event handlers
"change" event is same as "blur" event ."change" only fires if value of textBox has been changed so null/empty string is not applicable

Comment: I don't think onblur bubbles so detect is never called when blurring a textbox.

Comment: It does when you use addEventListener and set useCapture to true but it's not supported in IE8

Comment: @HMR are you talking about "blur" event

Comment: Yes, sorry. I see you updated your code. The change event should bubble

Comment: Note that your current code doesn't work in IE8 and doesn't work in FF. To get the event object you can do: `function detect(e){e=e||window.event;`

Answer (score 1):

Productivity is priority after performance, for me.

Since you're new, I would recommend a javascript library like jQuery.  With this, you can do a simple statement to put the `blur`/`keyup`/`change` events on all, and handle it in one organized place.

I have no doubt this can be done with pure javascript, but a major benefit of a javascript library is the increase in productivity by writing fewer lines.

In your specific case, I would do a jQuery `$.keyup()` on all `<input>`s via an empty css `class` and `if` or `switch` off another empty class to specify sub-textboxes:

```
$('.myEmptyClassThatsOnEachOfThe100Textboxes').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('myEmptyClassThatsOnEachTextboxOfThisFirstType')){
        //do stuff
    }
    else if(...
})
```

Comment: I agree to use jQuery if you're not familiar with all the quirks of non standard browsers. That is why I asked the OP if support for IE8. If that's not the case a "clean" js solution is possible. If the OP will use jQuery and needs support for IE8 then don't use version 2.* because since that version support for IE8 has been dropped. http://jquery.com/download/